# I believe his innocence or I believe him innocent.

Tags: grammar

Can we either say I believe his innocence or I believe him innocent?

Comment: You believe his version of events, so you believe **in** his innocence.

Comment: "His innocence" suggests that this quality is apparent or intrinsic, a bit like "his height" - not necessarily something open to belief. However, "I believe *in* his innocence" is quite standard, and means almost exactly the same as "I believe him innocent".